# How to manipulate list of DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of DateTime and separate variable DateTime

```
 List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>(); 
 DateTime date;
```

I'm trying to manipulate list in the way:

```
 list.ForEach(m=>m = new DateTime(date.Year,date.Month,date.Day,m.Hour,m.Minute,m.Second));
        return list;
```

list is filled, date is a date in proper format and it is not working. Why?

Comment: Is there even an entry in your list ?

Comment: Basic debugbging missing. The result: a question without any information. Worth only one thing - closing.

Comment: What are you iterating over to then add that to the list? At the moment it seems you are iterating a list of dates, to convert said date into a date and set that as the current item in the list, which makes no sense.

Comment: So you want to set every entry in your list to be *date*?

Comment: Probably what you need is `list.Select(m=>m = new DateTime(date.Year,date.Month,date.Day,m.Hour,m.Minute,m.Second)).ToList();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The item in your list that is referenced by `m` is not altered by your new assignment to `m` within your lambda expression. You are simply overwriting a temporary copy of the original value, not modifying the list's item.

To make actual alterations to the values within the list, Write a traditional loop using an indexer to modify the contents in place.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var m = list[i];
    list[i] = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, m.Hour, m.Minute, m.Second);
}
```

If you do not need to observe the changes in your original list and can instead (or even desire to) produce another, then you can follow the suggestions in comments and use Linq to produce a *new* list with your modifications.

```
list = list.Select(m => DateTime(date.Year,date.Month,date.Day,m.Hour,m.Minute,m.Second))
           .ToList();
```

Use the technique that best satisfies your use case.

Comment: ... or use LINQ to create a new list.

Comment: Many thanks to all people who cared to read my questins and actually help.